# Can you become "visible" by casting Disguise Self?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, invisibility, disguise

Some characters in my campaign were involved in a magical experiment. Said experiment went wrong and the participants were all afflicted with (randomly determined) side effects. One of the participants was a wizard and as a result of the failed experiment, she is now permanently invisible. This only affects her body though, and not the clothes she wears or the things she holds.

If she undresses completely and leaves behind all her gear, she is completely invisible and therefore gains all the associated benefits. But most of the time, she wears clothes and carries around a backpack, an arcane focus and other adventuring gear like that. This whole predicament has led to some interesting scenes.

Every now and then, this character would like to speak face to face with people, which is difficult while having an invisible face. Different methods to solve this problem were discussed. One of the potential options is for her to cast *disguise self*. Ideally, she could use that spell to let her body temporarily “reappear” as an illusion. But I am not sure if that would work.

In order to avoid a discussion about this being based on a magical homebrew effects, let me reframe this question:

Person A is under the effect of a *greater invisibility* spell and completely naked. This spell was originally cast by Person B, so Person A cannot stop concentrating in order to end the effect. Person A is also in the middle of a heated battle and must warn her deaf comrades (who are too far away to reach them) from incoming danger. So Person A has to become visible somehow, but the only spell Person A has available is *disguise self*.

**Can Person A become visible by casting *disguise self***, or would the illusion created by this spell be also invisible, because *greater invisibility* is a higher level illusion (affecting the same target)?

Comment: If this was indeed a spell, do the normal rules apply? Dispel Magic would remove it entirely, or is this something akin to the Potion Mixology table?

Comment: *because greater invisibility is a higher level illusion* — how is the greater invisibility spell related to the question?

Comment: She could also wear a mask to talk to people.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes

The spell Disguise Self is an illusion. It does not actually change your (invisible) form and the description points out:

> If you use this spell to add a hat to your outfits, objects pass
>   through the hat and anyone who touches it would feel nothing or would feel your head and hair.

and

> If you made yourself appear thinner then the hand of someone
>   touching you would bump into you while it was still seemingly in
>   midair.

From the description this illusion is obviously visible - cloaking your actual form - and, like any spell, your own state of (in)visibility doesn't matter.

This is not that different from casting Silent Image that "creates an image of an object or creature or some other visible phenomenon". This would also be visible regardless of the caster's visibility. Disguise Self is doing pretty much the same thing, except the illusion is restricted to a roughly humanoid form that is superimposed over your own body.

So I would say 'yes' you can render yourself temporarily visible with this spell.

Comment: Why would Disguise Self override your invisibility? You have two concurrent effects, what rules support that one overrides the other?

Comment: @NautArch I get the idea that this answer is pointing to the Disguise Self as providing another layer, like a sweater over a shirt, but I may be misunderstanding this.  PJRZ, can you provide some more detailed explanation on how the two different magical effects are acting on the invisible caster?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I see that as welll, but I don't see anything to support that idea (yet.)

Comment: To expound: Where in the rules does it say that the effect of any spell you cast is invisible if you are invisible? It doesn't. Obviously if the spell is merely altering something already exists and that object is invisible, then that won't change (unless the spell says so), but otherwise...if a spell creates a visible effect, then it continues to create a visible effect, regardless of the caster's state.

Comment: I also think it is clear that the "you make yourself...look different" line is explanatory text that is starting from an assumption of visibility, but is still not a "rule" regarding visibility that excepts what I've already said (and, anyway, making an invisible person look visible is still "making yourself look different"!)

Comment: @PJRZ I agree with your reasoning that spell effects remain visible even if the caster is invisible (and you've got my +1), but a question occurs to me. What about a spell like _blur_? Its effect is certainly visual. It is even an illusion spell, like _disguise self_. Would an invisible creature affected by _blur_ have a visible, blurry form? If not, where is the difference coming from?

Comment: What's the difference between and invisible blue jacket and an invisible red jacket?

Comment: @PJRZ can you fold a bit more of that into the answer? Anchoring your answer in a bit of the rules text from the spell description would support your idea; I also think that the spell description supports it. some of the points are *You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between* and *the extent of the illusion is  up to you* and *For example, if you use this spell to add a hat to your outfit.  Objects pass through the hat, and anyone who touches it  would feel nothing or would feel your head and hair* to support "adding another layer" with this spell.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and I think it’s pretty clear the effects don’t need to interact: the caster’s body is invisible, but the illusory body created by Alter Self is visible. There’s no contradiction there; Alter Self doesn’t make the caster visible, but creates a visible illusion that overlays and mirrors their body’s movements. It would still work if the caster closed their eyes, presumably, so not being able to see their own body is no impediment. Plus it’s temporary and uses up a spell slot so I think it’s a fair price to pay for overcoming a drawback for a while.

Comment: Just to add to this... according to this interpretation a PC with Disguise Self that fails to lose himself in a crowd then casts Invisibility and it fails utterly. Until you dismiss Disguise Self obviously. Interesting RP opportunity though.

Comment: @Slagmoth I’d run with that interpretation, sure. The only reason I can think of to not dismiss Alter Self in that scenario would be to hope you could resume the disguise after ceasing to be invisible without having to cast Alter Self again, but that seems like an edge case to me.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie Alter Self is entirely useless for this character except for the natural weapons and swimming stuff. Since you can't see her at all, ever.

Comment: @Slagmoth sorry, my mistake - I mean Disguise Self. I would alter my my comment but I can’t now you’ve replied to it.

Comment: On a slightly related but unofficial note - in Critical Role, one character cast Disguise Self on himself on entering (rather unwillingly!) the public baths. On undressing, Matt Mercer described his real clothes as apparently appearing from nowhere on to the floor while his illusory clothes stayed on!

Comment: But if you cast Disguise Self, and then cast Invisibility, you will be completely invisible, won't you?

Comment: @PJRZ I'd be wary of using Critical Role, etc to support any actual rules. I've listened to those and they are pretty fast and loose with the rules (which is okay!)

Comment: @NautArch: I did say "unofficial" and wouldn't use that to support actual rules. But just thought it was amusingly related!

Comment: @PJRZ Sho nuff! I just see a lot of comments referencing these games sometimes to support an opinion and wanted to put my caveat in :)

Answer (score 19):

### Yes or No — the DM has to make a decision

Disguise Self description has no details about being applied to permanently invisible targets. It's the DM's job to resolve situations like this, when a spell is being used in a non-standard way. See also [What is the source of the "spells do only what they say they do" rules interpretation principle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/)

The spell description says only that

> You make yourself—including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person— look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it. You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between. You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.

It is unclear if you can become visible using Disguise Self. As a DM, you can treat this both ways:

- **Yes** — since spell says it can create an illusion of clothes and face features "over" your own
- **No** — since spells do only what they say they do, and this spell explicitly says it makes you "look different", neither "make invisible", nor "make visible"

Apparently, you cannot become completely invisible using the Disguise Self spell. But **rules are silent** about the opposite situation — casting Disguise Self while being invisible in order to become visible. Since you are the DM, it's up to you to decide, how does this spell work in your world. Be consistent — make a decision and stick to it.

### Homebrew effects require homebrew adjudications

> she is now permanently invisible. This only affects her body though, and not the cloth she wears or the things she holds

I have to point it out, there is no such invisibility effect in 5e. Rules as written, you either completely invisible (including all your equipment), or you are visible. Being "partial invisible" raises new questions (does she get advantage on attack rolls and stealth checks, etc). If it is more like physical effect (transparent body tissues), and not an illusion, Disguise Self probably helps. If it is kind of a powerful illusion curse, 1-level spell probably won't be enough.

### Fun > Story > Rules

By its design, 5th edition chooses not to explicitly codify many things. The ambiguity in spell descriptions is actually a possibility, not a problem — as a DM, you can use the common sense and treat the rules the way would be better for the game. See Geek&Sundry "[How Watching Critical Role Made Me Better At D&D](https://geekandsundry.com/how-watching-critical-role-made-me-better-at-dd/)":

> A spell is typically written vague enough that you don’t have to worry about specific limitations unless you’re trying to stretch them. When in doubt, explain to the DM what you want to do and see if they’d be game

Keep in mind, that **the rules are a DM's tool**, not vice versa. As a DM, you use this tool to do the DM's job — to facilitate the enjoyment of the game for the players. See the [AL DM's guide](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/AL_DMG_YP.pdf) for more details:

> Always follow this golden rule when you DM for a group: Make decisions and adjudications that enhance the fun of the adventure when possible.

Putting it in a nut shell:

- If this helps the player, gives you a useful plot device and doesn't break anything — allow it
- If this makes things too easy for the player and seems too cheat-ish — don't allow it

Comment: Go not to the elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes.

Comment: I knew I would get this sort of answer, if I ask about something homwbrew. It's the usual "It's up to the GM, because it not official" answer. That's why I expanded the problem that showed up in a homebrew context and gave it an "official" context.

Comment: @hohenheim if you're not comfortable with this answer, could you please add the "good" answer criteria? what sort of answer do you want to get?

Comment: @ enkryptor: I will keep that in mind for my next question. thx

Comment: @hohenheim could you please add such criteria for this question? This would help other RPG.SE users

Answer (score 4):

## No.

The text of the *disguise self* spell describes its effect:

> You make yourself--including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person--look different...

This can change how you look (what your appearance is like) but it doesn't automatically mean anyone can see you. For example, you can change how you look in any number of ways (by casting *disguise self*, applying makeup, changing your clothes, receiving a scar, or so on), but if you're behind a wall or shrouded in total darkness then I still can't see how that might look.

In the case in question, you're under the effect of the invisibility condition from a spell (the specific spell doesn't actually matter). The text of the invisibility condition describes its effect:

> An invisible creature is impossible to see without the aid of magic or a special sense.

It doesn't matter whether your appearance *if* you were to be seen right now would be how you normally look or somehow different from normal. Nobody can perceive your appearance because you're literally impossible for anyone to see, so that change goes unseen, barring the following exception.

If someone has "the aid of magic or a special sense" then they would be able to see you despite the invisibility, and you would appear to them as you look under the effects of *disguise self*. To revisit the previous examples, if I use *clairvoyance* then I can see you despite the wall, or if I have darkvision then I can see you despite the darkness.

(Note that *disguise self* itself is not "the aid of magic" because the text is passively describing the capability of onlookers to see you; they're the ones that would need to benefit from such aid, not you. Examples of such aid are *see invisibility* and truesight. The only way *disguise self* would aid onlookers is if it canceled your invisibility or if it made you able to be seen despite your invisibility in a case of specific beating general, but the text of the spell does not.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Nobody can see how you look because you're invisible." and specifically how/why greater invisibility masks the effect of disguise self?

Comment: If you're invisible, you're impossible to see, so nobody can see how you look. There are any number of things that can change how you look: makeup, mundane disguise kits, changing your clothes, getting a scar. If somebody can't see you because you're literally impossible to see then they have no way to notice that change in your appearance.

Comment: I understand the vernacular meaning of invisible and the condition.  I was suggesting you cite the text of greater invisibility and the invisible condition to specifically point out why this is the case.

Comment: I did cite the text of the invisibility condition. It's in quotation marks in my answer. I don't see how the specific spell granting the condition impacts the answer.

Comment: The invisible condition includes a clause about "without magical aid".  Disguise self could be construed as a magical aid.  That could be addressed.  The language about "belongings on your person" is mirrored in the greater invisibility description.  Seems like making it on the nose obvious would improve the answer.

Comment: Noted. I'll think about how to clarify that.

Comment: @Grosscol I revised a bunch. Please let me know if this addresses the particular interactions you were talking about.

Comment: I think  this is taking the text a bit too literal and even then I don't agree with this interpretation. They're ability to see you? All of it still falls under the realm of 'aid of magic'. That sentence has no qualifiers where the aid of magic comes from.

Comment: If you have a suggestion for improvement, please let me know. If you just disagree, that's what downvoting is for.